# How to create an machine-readable logfile in PHP (probably with fscanf)

Tags: php, file, scanf, logfiles

I want to create a simple logfile *in PHP* that later can be read *by PHP*.

This logfile should look like this:

```
1303942306 26.4 "Lore ipsum 1" 84.169.73.55 appname1 
1303942308 28.8 "Lore ipsum 2" 84.169.73.55 appname2
1304078658 31.2 "Lore ipsum 3" 80.187.103.95 appname3
```

As you can see it is supposed to contain the following variables:

```
$timestamp
$float
$text (with spaces and other special characters)
$ip
$appname
```

Until now there was no need to save text (with spaces) within this logfile, so I could use a simple fscanf function.

I've tried to use "|" as a delimiter with fscanf - but, well, it has a few "glitches" ;-):

```
//write to file
$statisticsfile = fopen("user.history",'a+b');
     fputs($statisticsfile, time().' | '.$float.' | '.$text.' | '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' | '.$appname."\r\n");

//read from file
    while ($userinfo = fscanf($statisticsfile, "%[0-9] | %[0-9.-] | %[a-zA-Z0-9 ,] | %[0-9.] | %[0-9]")) 
{list ($timestamp[], $float[], $text[], $ip[], $appname[]) = $userinfo;}
```

This code creates three problems:

1. It skips the first line in the logfile
2. the text can only contain letters and number (and all other special characters I have defined), but it such a better design if I could only exclude the delimiter
3. is fscanf really the best (fastest, least memory-consuming) function for this task? Or would a simple fget function with a delimiter be better?

I would really appreciate your help ;-)

Comment: `26.4` is a strange integer...

Comment: @Dagon: why would you use a db for this? Why doesn't Apache use a db for this?

Comment: @PeeHaa I've fixed the strange integer - it's now a good old floating point... ;-)

Comment: because of the large number of ways to manipulate the data the db affords. if you want Apache to log access to the db you just use mod_log_sql

Comment: You should only use `fscanf` as a complement to `fprintf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample data, seems to me that the best way to go is the built-in csv functions, [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). Simply use a space as your delimiter instead of a comma. These functions will automatically be mindful of the quoted values.

Comment: Hey, I've tried your function - but unfortunately my code seems to consumes much more time and memory. Could you (or anybody else) have a look (I'm a PHP beginner...) http://ideone.com/3UWXC

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a much easier way to do this, but one slightly long regex solution to not needing a delimiter could be

```
$reg = /^(\d{10})\s(\d+[\.]\d*)\s"(.*?)"\s\b((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))\b\s(\w+)$/;
```

the ip capturing group makes it look worse then it is.

which you could then use to make & break lines of text like so...
http://ideone.com/hCvPy